# Можно ли получить данные от GeoIP2 на русском (хотя бы только город) и как?

Tags: python, django

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
>>> g = GeoIP2()
>>> g.city('72.14.207.99')
{'city': 'Mountain View',
'country_code': 'US',
'country_name': 'United States',
'dma_code': 807,
'latitude': 37.419200897216797,
'longitude': -122.05740356445312,
'postal_code': '94043',
'region': 'CA',
'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles'}
```

Можно ли получить город на русском, или придётся писать словарь, который будет переводить с анг на рус?

Comment: А как по-вашему будет «Mountain View» на русском?

Comment: Не судите строго, с джангой я не так давно связался, так что пока разбираюсь. Объясните пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Просто названия городов обычно не переводят. Под переводом вы подразумеваете транслитерацию?

Comment: Нет, это не совсем то, моя задача вывести пользователю на русском его страну, город. Но я придумал как решу эту задачу (с помощью js).